# How do you show AJAX call result, when the user moved to other pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, signalr

I have a long running function in server side, and it is called via AJAX. 
But after user sent the AJAX request, they could move to other pages. I don't want to show an AJAX spinner to block users.

How can I show the AJAX call results even user move to other pages?
Should I consider to use SignalR?

Thanks.

Update:
I am using ASP.Net MVC, jQuery, AngularJs, but my application is not a single page application.

Comment: If the user has moved on, you can't alert them to the result. You should include an AJAX abort call in the window.onbeforeunload event.

Comment: supposing you are using angularJS (from the tag you included) you should have a single page application while using `ngRoute` for the URLs, so you shouldn't care about "moving to different pages"

Comment: If your calls to the back end are handled in a service rather than a controller, then there's no reason you can't store the results of the call in the service until the user returns to a view that is capable of displaying the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show the AJAX result in another page, as soon as you leave a page your JS processes are killed.

One solution would be to push the results to the client (using web sockets or something like that) when the complex function has finished running, or handle the page reloading with AJAX as well to avoid an actual page refresh.

Comment: The JS processes are stopped, but if the AJAX call has already initiated a server-side process, that will continue. This is why making an abort call in the window's onbeforeunload event would make sense.

Comment: That's true, but what I meant is that the code to handle the AJAX call success won't run if you refresh the page, even if the server process finishes and return something. If he uses websockets to push the completion event to the client from the server, it will work even after reload.

I'm not familiar with AJAX abord calls, but doesn't that mean that the process on the server will never finish/complete? Maybe the process should still complete and return something, even if the user has moved to another page.

Comment: actually OP asks about using `SignalR` which is *web-sockets or something like that*

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for results to be stored and pulled somewhere else for later use, you would initiate a HTTP or Websocket request that kicks off some type of task que, that you then can use AJAX or Websockets later to check the status/result of the job/task.

What you're trying to do is store results locally which is not how this type of thing works. If you're a initiating a ajax request it means you're hitting some kind of API which means the API endpoint should be the keyholder, not the user's browser.

You could initiate a request that then follows a user wherever they go similar to how facebook works. You send a message, go to a entirely new page, and the message box still appears because it's already loading the javascript that initiates the calls to the server to grab the information. To-do list examples on the web are already a good example of this. You could put a to-do list on every page, tie it into SignalR. No storing of information in the browser though, just losts of ajax requests for the results of the original request. Or in the case of SignlR websocket connections monitoring the server side objects.